# Run puppet exec on file update right from the first apply

Tags: puppet

I want to run a puppet exec-resource based on a file update. Something like:

```
File { '/tmp/foo.bar':
    audit => content,
} ~>
exec { 'deployment':
    command => 'do_something_meaningful.sh',
}
```

But this gets executed on every puppet-apply-run. Even if the file has not changed. So I tried the exec-attribute `refreshonly`. But with this, the exec gets not executed on the first puppet-apply. I think this is because there is yet no md5-checksum at the `state.yml`. It works great from the second run.

My current workaround is something like this:

```
File { '/tmp/foo.bar':
    audit => content,
} 

exec { 'deployment_on_change':
    command     => 'do_something_meaningful.sh',
    refreshonly => true,
    subscribe   => File['/tmp/foo.bar']
}

exec {'deployment_on_first_run':
    command   => 'do_something_meaningful.sh',
    onlyif    => 'test ! -f marker.file',
    subscribe   => File['/tmp/foo.bar']
} ->
file { 'marker.file':
    ensure => present
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this fully, with `refreshonly => true` it also gets applied on the first run for me (and second but then not anymore)

Answer (score 0):

You're forcing Puppet into something that it's not designed for. By executing you would only prolong each Puppet run. And you don't want that.

Simply use a `cron` job, that will check if something has changed.

```
file{'/usr/bin/local/do_something_meaningful':
  ensure  => present,
  owner   => 'myuser',
  mode    => '0755',
  source  => 'puppet:///modules/my_module/do_something_meaningful.sh',
}

cron { 'do_something_meaningful':
  command => '/usr/bin/local/do_something_meaningful',
  user    => 'myuser',
  hour    => ['8-17'],
  minute  => '*/30',
  require => File['/usr/bin/local/do_something_meaningful'],
}
```

If you're deploying code using some other tool, you should hook `do_something_meaningful.sh` into the deployment process. Puppet is good for ensuring that some resource (files, packages, services, etc.) exists.